# Hibernate not fetching from Second Level Cache if ID column is VARCHAR

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, second-level-cache

I am trying Spring Boot and Hibernate Second Level Caching. I was successful in getting it to work. However, I am stuck with a strange scenario where entities are not fetched from the second level cache if the ID column is a VARCHAR. Here are the relevant classes:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "user1")
@Entity
public class User {
    private long userId;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

This Entity works fine, here are the debug logs from hibernate for first and second fetch

**Fetch 1**

```
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user0_.id as id1_1_0_,     user0_.name as name2_1_0_ from user1 user0_ where user0_.id=?
o.h.l.p.e.p.i.ResultSetProcessorImpl     : Starting ResultSet row #0
l.p.e.p.i.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl : On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for  [com.voyant.master.entities.User#1]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Adding entity to second-level cache: [com.voyant.master.entities.User#1]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.voyant.master.entities.User#1]
o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl   : HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
.l.e.p.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader : Done entity load : com.voyant.master.entities.User#1
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
```

**Fetch 2**

```
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
```

Now, the problematic Entity definition:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity
public class User2 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }  

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User2(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User2() {
    } 
}
```

Hibernate debug logs from two consecutive fetch of same entity

**Fetch 1**

```
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
o.h.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from User2 as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.username=:param0
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user2x0_.username as username1_0_, user2x0_.lastname as lastname2_0_, user2x0_.name as name3_0_ from user user2x0_ where user2x0_.username=?
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Adding entity to second-level cache: [com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.voyant.master.entities.User2{name=dharam, username=dharam, lastname=dharam}
```

**Fetch 2**

```
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : begin
o.h.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl       : Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from User2 as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.username=:param0
org.hibernate.SQL                        : select user2x0_.username as username1_0_, user2x0_.lastname as lastname2_0_, user2x0_.name as name3_0_ from user user2x0_ where user2x0_.username=?
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving associations for [com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Adding entity to second-level cache: [com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.voyant.master.entities.User2#dharam]
o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Processing flush-time cascades
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Dirty checking collections
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects
o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener    : Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : Listing entities:
o.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter  : com.voyant.master.entities.User2{name=dharam, username=dharam, lastname=dharam}
```

Comment: can you please change your user class to implements Serializable and see if it works.  *********public class User implements Serializable {

Comment: Sorry! the user class is all fine. The problem is with User2 class, but yes! I will try what you suggested.

Comment: apologize I meant the one which is having issues.

Comment: Tried! but no luck. BTW Thanks for reading the lengthy question and giving it a try.

Comment: No problem. read the below article https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-types

Comment: I am reading but isn't it strange. I mean, just changing the data type of ID opens a whole new problem. I debugged hibernate, realized that the code flow for two cases is completely different. It never hits the code to fetch from Second Level Cache

Comment: As per the article --------------->"Serializing and caching issue
If the value type, in our case History, does not implement the java.io.Serializable interface, then its respective custom type is responsible for properly serializing or deserializing the value type. Otherwise, the value-type instances cannot be cached by the Hibernate second-level cache service". That's y I asked to make it serilizable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149844/discussion-between-dharam-and-user8271644).

Comment: Try adding this in user2*********>

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid" )
private String username;

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem and hence making a log here so that if someone faces this in future, it might prove to be a time saver.

As we know that the second level cache works on ID column (where the ID can be string, integer, long etc). This only works when you use the `findOne(id)` method to fetch object.

If by any chance you defined a findByUsername(String username) method in your repository and use this to fetch the entity, this will be cached. However, the second fetch wont even bother to query from the cache.

The relevant code is in `RepositoryFactorySupport.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvokce()` method. Where you can clearly see the below:

```
Method method = invocation.getMethod();
Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();

if (isCustomMethodInvocation(invocation)) {

    Method actualMethod = repositoryInformation.getTargetClassMethod(method);
    return executeMethodOn(customImplementation, actualMethod, arguments);
}

if (hasQueryFor(method)) {
    return queries.get(method).execute(arguments);
}

// Lookup actual method as it might be redeclared in the interface
// and we have to use the repository instance nevertheless
Method actualMethod = repositoryInformation.getTargetClassMethod(method);
return executeMethodOn(target, actualMethod, arguments);
```

There are three code paths based on the conditions:

1. If there is a custom method invocation
2. If there is a query for the method
3. Or it is an actual method.

**Lesson learnt** If there is an id defined, use the framework methods for querying based on the IDs, do not write your custom good looking methods :)